# How do i display a ChoiceType key in a twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig, formbuilder

Lets say i'm building the following form with symfony form builder:

```
$builder->add('version', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices'   => [
        'Wheezy'    => 7,
        'Jessie'    => 8,
        'Stretch'   => 9
    ]
])
```

Later i need to access it from a twig template for instance to display a table:

```
...
<td>{{ entity.version }}</td>
<td>{{ entity.foo }}</td>
<td>{{ entity.bar }}</td>
...
```

If i do this, i will end up with a version equal to **7**, **8**, or **9**, and i don't want to do the following which will obviously defeat it's purpose:

```
$builder->add('version', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices'   => [
        'Wheezy'    => "Wheezy",
        'Jessie'    => "Jessie",
        'Stretch'   => "Stretch"
    ]
])
```

How can i do this without having to map it inside my template ? i also really want to avoid doing a whole entity, would be an overkill for so few entries. I'm pretty sure or at least i hope that there is something to handle this case scenario already bundled with symfony, thanks.

Comment: What are you getting and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As i said, i try to display the key name Wheezy, Jessie, or Stretch instead of the values 7, 8, or 9 inside a twig template, updated to clarify more.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30846583/symfony2-twig-iterate-over-select-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to go with this, but it will use more space in your database:

```
$builder->add('version', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices'   => [
        'Wheezy'    => "Wheezy",
        'Jessie'    => "Jessie",
        'Stretch'   => "Stretch"
    ]
]);
```

Or handle it in your entity, for example:

```
class Entity {
    const VERSIONS = [
        'Wheezy'  => 7,
        'Jessie'  => 8,
        'Stretch' => 9
    ];

    // code

    public function getVersion($string = false) {
        if ($string && \in_array($this->version, self::VERSIONS))
            return \array_search($this->version, self::VERSIONS);

        return $this->version;
    }
}
```

In your form builder you just need to set the choices to the Entity list of versions.

```
$builder->add('version', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices' => Entity::VERSIONS
]);
```

And finally set your getter $string value to true in your template

```
...
<td>{{ entity.version(true) }}</td>
<td>{{ entity.foo }}</td>
<td>{{ entity.bar }}</td>
...
```

By default, the behavior of the getter getVersion will act as normal, if you set the $string boolean parameter to true, it will render the value as a string

**Edit:**
You didn't add any information about PHP version, so I assumed that you use at least version 7.0, thus the return type declaration. Also note that you need at least PHP 5.6 to use array as a constant's value.

Comment: Setting the map in the class is a ok solution, but if you are returning a string directly from the class, when you will edit, the form will not recognize the value, and will leave the select field blank.

Comment: Then you can create the getter with an optional parameter and map the value if the parameter is set to true. Besides from that, why don't you use the strings instead of 7,8,9?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what i have done. Also i'm not using strings for optimisation purpose, with a smallint i'm using (entries * 2) bytes, with a string i'm using (entries * (string lenght + 1)). now imagine a table with hundred of thousands entries.