# Symfony5 forms - render radio input inside label

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony5

I want to render inputs of type radio inside their labels because I want to use flexbox to justify them with space between each.

Here's part from a RegistrationType class

```
...
        ->add('gender', ChoiceType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => false,
            'label' => false,
            'choices' => [
                'male' => 'male',
                'female' => 'female',
                'other' => 'other',
            ],
        ])
```

Configure options of this class are default:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => User::class,
    ]);
}
```

I want to acheive given result:

```html
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:space-between; width:22rem;">
                <label>
                    <input  type="radio" 
                            name="registration_form[gender]" 
                            required="required" 
                            class="required" 
                            value="male">

                            Male
                </label>
                
                <label>
                    <input  type="radio" 
                            name="registration_form[gender]" 
                            required="required" 
                            class="required" 
                            value="female">

                            Female
                </label>
                
                <label>
                    <input  type="radio" 
                            name="registration_form[gender]" 
                            required="required" 
                            class="required" 
                            value="other">

                            Other
                </label>
                
            </div>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30846583/symfony2-twig-iterate-over-select-options) here, and supported by the [Field Variables of the ChoiceType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#field-variables) class, you might access the `.choices` attribute and loop through it like so:

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:space-between; width:22rem;">
    {{ form_label(form.gender) }}
    <div>
    {% for key,val in form.gender.vars.choices %}
    <label>
        <input type="radio" 
            name="{{ form.gender.vars.full_name }}" 
            required="required"
            class="required"
            value="{{ val.value }}"
        />
        {{ val.label | trans }} />
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

There are more elegant ways of customizing, like creating or overriding a [Form Theme](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html), or, perhaps using a [twig macro](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/macro.html) to keep your code somewhat DRY. If you go the form theme route, look into the way that the attributes [block](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/block.html) is used – we bypass much of the utility it gives in this example above.

Comment: Thank You! Your solution works as expected after minor changes. Form themes look interesting and I will read more about them and macros. I'm just a beginner in using Symfony.

Comment: I would add that even if the form element was rendered, symfony still renders it at the end. I don't understand this mechanism, but it seems that symfony "have to" render all form elements if they are not specified in between form_start and form_end in twig. Given solution doesn't prevent this behaviour.

Comment: Good catch! If you're confident your template renders all that needs rendering, close with `form_end(form, {'render_rest': false})`. (Otherwise a theme override would use form_widget, and signal that the field has been rendered already.)

Comment: It works and everything's perfect. Thank You once again. :-)